# Python dictionary from API has 1 heading I want to get rid of

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv

so this is what i get from the API, but I really dont need the first "dividends" heading

```
{
    "dividends": [
        {
            "currency": "USD",
            "date": "2021-05-04",
            "dividend": "0.1100",
            "dividend_prior": "",
            "dividend_type": "Cash",
            "dividend_yield": "0.0878828229027963",
            "ex_dividend_date": "2021-05-18",
            "exchange": "AMEX",
            "frequency": 12,
            "id": "6091befc99cf5000019edaf3",
            "importance": 0,
            "name": "Pioneer Diversified High",
            "notes": "",
            "payable_date": "2021-05-28",
            "record_date": "2021-05-19",
            "ticker": "HNW",
            "updated": 1620164698
        },
        {
            "currency": "USD",
            "date": "2021-05-04",
            "dividend": "0.0475",
            "dividend_prior": "",
            "dividend_type": "Cash",
            "dividend_yield": "0.0449526813880126",
            "ex_dividend_date": "2021-05-18",
            "exchange": "NYSE",
            "frequency": 12,
            "id": "6091bf0999cf5000019edaff",
            "importance": 0,
            "name": "Pioneer Municipal High IT",
            "notes": "",
            "payable_date": "2021-05-28",
            "record_date": "2021-05-19",
            "ticker": "MHI",
            "updated": 1620164711
        },
```

I got it working with header=False, but when put into a csv file it doesnt take the correct new headers from this

```
        "currency": "USD",
        "date": "2021-05-04",
        "dividend": "0.1100",
        "dividend_prior": "",
        "dividend_type": "Cash",
        "dividend_yield": "0.0878828229027963",
        "ex_dividend_date": "2021-05-18",
        "exchange": "AMEX",
        "frequency": 12,
        "id": "6091befc99cf5000019edaf3",
        "importance": 0,
        "name": "Pioneer Diversified High",
        "notes": "",
        "payable_date": "2021-05-28",
        "record_date": "2021-05-19",
        "ticker": "HNW",
        "updated": 1620164698
```

The output of that looks like this: [image: see image]

shouldnt it take the headers and put them as the column names and then align everything according to columns?

this is the code that ive used so far:

```
response_dumped = json.dumps(response)
response_parsed = json.loads(response_dumped)
df = pd.DataFrame(response_parsed)
df.to_csv("main_data.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, select data by key `dividends`:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(esponse_parsed['dividends'])
```

Comment: this gives me an error saying: df = pd.DataFrame(response_dumped['dividends'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
but using 0 or 1 instead of 'dividends' gives me the following error:

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: actually I found a solution
instead of response_dumped I used response_parsed because that was the one that i did json.loads on and then your solution worked, so thank you

Comment: @AlexanderSchmitt - You are right, I edit it in my answer 4 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

````
import pandas as pd
json = {
    "dividends": [
        {
            "currency": "USD",
            "date": "2021-05-04",
            "dividend": "0.1100",
            "dividend_prior": "",
            "dividend_type": "Cash",
            "dividend_yield": "0.0878828229027963",
            "ex_dividend_date": "2021-05-18",
            "exchange": "AMEX",
            "frequency": 12,
            "id": "6091befc99cf5000019edaf3",
            "importance": 0,
            "name": "Pioneer Diversified High",
            "notes": "",
            "payable_date": "2021-05-28",
            "record_date": "2021-05-19",
            "ticker": "HNW",
            "updated": 1620164698
        },
        {
            "currency": "USD",
            "date": "2021-05-04",
            "dividend": "0.0475",
            "dividend_prior": "",
            "dividend_type": "Cash",
            "dividend_yield": "0.0449526813880126",
            "ex_dividend_date": "2021-05-18",
            "exchange": "NYSE",
            "frequency": 12,
            "id": "6091bf0999cf5000019edaff",
            "importance": 0,
            "name": "Pioneer Municipal High IT",
            "notes": "",
            "payable_date": "2021-05-28",
            "record_date": "2021-05-19",
            "ticker": "MHI",
            "updated": 1620164711
        }]}
no_header = json["dividends"]
df = pd.DataFrame(no_header)
df.to_csv("main_data.csv", index=False, header=False)


```
````